# read from text file and send in to aws sqs Fifo queue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a little issue here. I want to read from a text file using python and create queue and then send these lines from the text file into Amazon web services SQS(Simple Queue service). First of all, I`ve actually managed to do this using boto, but the problem is that the lines dont come in order, just randomly, like line 4,line 1, line 5 etc etc..
Here is my code:

```
import boto.sqs

conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("us-east-2",
                                  aws_access_key_id='AKIAIJIQZG5TR3NMW3LQ',
                                  aws_secret_access_key='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')

q = conn.create_queue('test')
with open('read.txt', 'r') as read_file:
    from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage
    for line in read_file:
        m = RawMessage()
        m.set_body(line)
        q.write(m)
```

So, what to do? Well, we need to create an FIFO queue(which I also managed to do using boto3 in python), but now the problem is that I have problems reading the text file.. Here is the code i used to create a FIFO queue in SQS:

```
import boto3

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'AKIAIJIQZG5TR3NMW3LQ'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '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'
sqs_client = boto3.resource(
    'sqs',
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name='us-east-2'
)

queue_name = ('demo_queue.fifo')

response = sqs_client.create_queue(
    QueueName=queue_name,
    Attributes={
        'FifoQueue': 'true',
        'ContentBasedDeduplication': 'true'
    }
)
with open('read.txt', 'r') as read_file:
    from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage
    for line in read_file:
        m = RawMessage()
        m.set_body(line)
        queue_name.write(m)
```

Somebody know how to solve this? thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I get the error message: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: queue_name, in your case, is a string `queue_name = ('demo_queue.fifo')`, you probably want to use some different object.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`queue_name.write(m)`

with 

`response.write(m)`

in your first piece of code. You should use the actual queue returned by `get_queue_by_name`
Also, when only specifying MessageBody and MessageGroupID in boto3, make sure that Content-Based deduplication is enabled for the queue, or specify a MessageDeduplicationId string, otherwise it will fail

Comment: I`ve tried, but now I get the error message:

AttributeError: 'sqs.Queue' object has no attribute 'write'